# Geoxml - 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: геолокация

С каких-то пор, как файл Xml разросся из-за большого количества точек, он перестал целиком открываться :(

То есть открывается, но частично, на всё остальное выдает следующее:

```
geoxml.xml:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)
geoxml.xml:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)
geoxml.xml:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)
geoxml.xml:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)
```

Модуль **deflate** стоит, тестеры показывают, что всё ок, сайт сжат.
Пример: [карта дорожных проблем](http://spbauto.org/problem_map)

Нужно выбрать **За всё время**, тогда загрузчик клинит.

Куда копать? Что делать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Где открываться? Чем вы его открываете?

Comment: Карта его пытается загрузить...

Comment: Какая карта? Как загрузить? Где - на клиенте или на сервере? Код будет?